# TP Link TL-WN725N (v2) driver install issue

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, 16.10

I first went through the process in the official docs, running the following in the Driver directory:

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

This seemed to error more than it should, and also didn't show up as a wireless device via `ifconfig`

It seems to be showing there as a wired connection:

(Note: I do have a phone connected for a USB tethered connection as well)

```
enp0s29f7u1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.42.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
    inet6 fe80::56a7:45cb:9bc3:1cf9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 26:40:47:46:12:94  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 6113  bytes 4309408 (4.3 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6430  bytes 1073581 (1.0 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether e0:cb:4e:1f:3b:60  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 19109  bytes 1196738 (1.1 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 19109  bytes 1196738 (1.1 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The USB device does show up from running `lsusb`, as:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
```

This is the output from `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: c0
   serial: e0:cb:4e:1f:3b:60
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:28 memory:feac0000-feafffff ioport:ec00(size=128)

  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: enp0s29f7u1
   serial: 26:40:47:46:12:94
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.6 link=yes multicast=yes
```

I then tried this process as detailed at the page [here](http://brilliantlyeasy.com/ubuntu-linux-tl-wn725n-tp-link-version-2-wifi-driver-install/), as such:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd rtl8188eu
make all
make install
insmod 8188eu.ko
```

For good measure I also tried installing this, but to no avail: https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtl8192cu-dkms_0.2_all.deb

I now have 2 wired connections showing, and am confused as to next steps forward ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
cd ~
rm -r rtl8188eu
```

If it is not there, that's fine, just continue:

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd rtl8188eu
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

It 'makes' perfectly on my 4.8.0-34 kernel; however, if you encounter any errors, please post them.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Comment: From 'make clean', the errors in order:  `make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'. Stop.  make: *** No targets. Stop.  make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop.  modprobe: FATAL: Module 8188eu not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-34-generic`

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: I assume you meant to cd into the rtl8188eu folder before running make, and I had to sudo one or two of the others too. It's difficult to comment with big output here, so please see this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/RZEwp6hu)

Comment: I certainly did not intend for you to compile this in /usr/src/linux-headers-etc.! Please see my edit above in a few moments. Also, when any step ends in an error, all of the following steps will also fail, so there is no need to continue.

Comment: Yes it seemed a little strange, as believed I cloned into my home before, maybe not then.  Good news though as look like we're getting closer :)  Some nice healthy output from this make (see [here](http://pastebin.com/YfM030Ux)).  Now we have 'Enable Wifi' in the system network dropdown! However 'Wi-Fi Networks' in the same place is greyed out .. I looked at dmesg and saw some possible issue (see [here](http://pastebin.com/xbkV2bWV)).

Comment: I don't see any possible issue with the wireless driver. I suggest that you detach the USB ethernet and reboot. Then show us a paste of: `dmesg | grep -e 8188 -e wlx`and also: `sudo iwlist scan`

Comment: Another step closer! My Wi-Fi network now shows after a reboot, however there appears to be no signal being received, the password is not excepted, and the tethered phone connection I was using is receiving some kind of DNS failure all of a sudden (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG from Chrome). I'm not sure how this all relates to each other. Anyway, here's the output(s) that you requested (I believe the first is from before the wired / tethered connection dropped, and the 2nd after): [output before](http://pastebin.com/0nE7QA1Z), [output after](http://pastebin.com/0eUbW25X)

Comment: Please see my edit above. Your driver and old Chili hate hate hate TKIP.

Comment: There was a fleeting connection for maybe 30s! I set the router to WPA2-AES, and set my reg permanently. Aside from that I'm not sure switching the channel is a good idea as there's 4 other people sharing this connection in my shared home, and I don't know how much that would effect their connections (dropping, possibility of reconnecting etc). There doesn't seem to be settings for the other you mentioned on ('Virgin Superhub' router).

Comment: I really wish Linux wasn't like this, it's things like this that put me of using it. 3rd party hardware is just always (usually) an absolute complete nightmare! :) I don't know what else to try, as this looked like one of the best options. If you have any suggestions of a wifi solution that may (will? who knows :) work, I'd be grateful. Thanks a lot for your generosity thus far ...

Comment: I have and recommend this: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B002SZEOLG/

Comment: OK cool - if you think it'll work well in GB. It's on the UK site :) http://amzn.eu/jfgSMH2

Comment: Should be perfect. Great price, too!

Comment: Sweet, chili .. ordered. Found an even (slightly) cheaper one, with free delivery! Cheeky Amazon kept trying to redirect me to the other one from my wish list :) [here she be](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B002SZEOLG/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A17AS5ETPMZ9A1) - seriously cheeky, the shortlink / link they generate from that page points to the more expensive one they sell ..

Comment: Ok cool - I have a connection with that device! It does seem pretty slow compared to my other devices, even though the signal to the router is fairly good. Did you do any other config other than plug and play?

Comment: "Seems" slow is pretty subjective. What does this tell you compared to other devices? http://www.speedtest.net/

Comment: Apologies for the late reply.. It seems very odd, did you install any other drivers or use it out of the box (as I have)? I'm guessing it must be a config issue as pages barely load, even though there looks to be a reasonable connection to the router. For a clearer picture I've run a speed test on that and my Windows machine right next to it. Windows results: [here](http://www.thinkbroadband.com/speedtest/results.html?id=1487191692241563555) - Ubuntu results: [here](http://www.thinkbroadband.com/speedtest/results.html?id=1487188296685035855). speedtest.net wouldn't even load(!)

Comment: I just use the default drivers. I suggest you start a new question and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: It seems that the 3 areas in which the desktop machine was placed for testing were all wifi dead-zones. After using an extension cable the signal is much better... Thank you again